# print numbers between 1- 20 using rules

Tags: javascript

I am going through codeacademys JavaScript tutorials as i am new to it. The tutorial asks for the following:

Print out the numbers from 1 - 20.

The rules:

- For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".

- For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".

- For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in the console.

- Otherwise, just print out the number.

Here is my code:

```
for (i=1; i<=20; i++) {

if(i%3==0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
} 
if(i%5==0){
    console.log("Buzz");
}else if (i%5==0 && i%3==0) {
    console.log("fizzBuzz");
} else {
    console.log(i);
}

}
```

i am getting an error saying that i am printing out the wrong number of items, anyone know why that is?

Comment: What *is* being output by your code?

Comment: The output should be a list that prints out "Fizz" if the number is divisible by 3, "Buzz" if the number is divisible by 5 and "FizzBuzz" if the number is both divisible by 3 and 5 otherwise just print out the number

Comment: It is checking for each line that you output. `console.log` adds a newline at the end of your output. So for numbers divisible by 15, it is printing Fizz and Buzz on separate lines. Also, your third code block can never be executed. (It will execute only if i%5==0 is false and i%5==0 is true; see the problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the value is divisible by 3 and not by 5, on the first If statement "Fizz" is printed.

Then on the second if statement, the last else is hit so the number will also be printed. You will need to change the if(i%5==0) to else if.

However there will be a problem now when (i%5==0 && i%3==0) as the else if for that will never be hit. You can fix this by putting this as the first comparison and changing the output to FizzBuzz.

Like this:

```
for ( i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
};
```

Make sure you understand why this fixes your issue before you move on as you will most likely make the same mistake again.

Add a comment if you would like me to explain clearer if you are struggling to work out why you have gone wrong.

Comment: I understand the first bit of what you said however, please could you clarify and explain why you used an else if for the other conditions?

Comment: Hi sure I'll try and explain for you. If the else if's weren't there, it would check each if statement to see if it is true. This is fine when (i%5==0) is true but if it is false the last else will be hit even if (i%5==0). For example, if you set i = 6 then run through in your head, (i%5==0 && i%3==0) is false so skip that if, (i%3==0) is true so print "Fizz", (i%5==0) is false so go to the else. This means "6" would also be printed which is not what we want. Using else if means that once we get an if that is true, the rest of the other ifs are ignored.

Comment: There would also be a problem when using a number divisble by both 3 and 5 because the first if would be hit so "FizzBuzz" would be printed but then the other ifs would also be checked so it would then go on to print"Fizz" and then "Buzz" again so you would get 3 lines output, one with "FizzBuzz", then one with "Fizz" and then one with "Buzz".

Answer (score 2):

The check for both 3 and 5 must be first, otherwise the two other statements are true already and give separate logs. Now you print FizzBuzz in a single `console.log` statement.

```
   for (i=1; i<=20; i++) {

      if (i%5==0 && i%3==0) {
          console.log("FizzBuzz");
      } else if(i%3==0) {
          console.log("Fizz");
      } else if(i%5==0){
          console.log("Buzz");
      } else {
          console.log(i);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if a number is divisible by both 3 and 5 in your first IF, since numbers that are divisible by both would otherwise result in the first and the second IF statement being executed.

Furthermore, the rules tell you to write out "FizzBuzz" in case a number is divisible by both, and at the moment you're only printing out "Buzz".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it out yourself? Because when you run it you get this output:

```
1
2
"Fizz"
3
4
"Buzz"
"Fizz"
6
7
8
"Fizz"
9
"Buzz"
11
"Fizz"
12
13
14
"Fizz"
"Buzz"
16
17
"Fizz"
18
19
"Buzz"
```

As you can see, you are printing out the number even when you printed `Fizz` and also you are actually supposed to print `FizzBuzz` in a single line, instead of two separate ones.

To fix the former issue you should take a look at your if/else structure. You have a separate if at the beginning just for `Fizz`. After that, you are handling the `Buzz` separately as well and if there’s no match for it, it will print out the number. So although you already printed `Fizz` you are still going to the last `else`. So you should combine those two separate if blocks into a single one.

The other issue is that `console.log` will always write a separate line. So in your case where you check for all the `FizzBuzz` conditions, you should print `FizzBuzz`. You will also want to check that first, otherwise the `Buzz` condition will hit first without giving you a chance to print `FizzBuzz`.

Comment: Yes i tried it out myself but i am gettting an error hence forth i cannot proceed to my next tutorial on this website

Comment: Your code does not produce an error. The website comparing the output with the correct one produces the error (because your output is not correct). In that case, you should try your solution separately on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try walking through the logic by hand.  If `i` is `1`, then only the last block works.  If `i` is `3`, the first block works.  If `i` is `5`, the second block works.  And if `i` is `15`, the second block works, and the third never gets a chance.

In general, have the most restrictive conditions run before the least restrictive.  You should also notice and check carefully when two of your blocks are dissimilar.  You have four blocks, and only one is an `else` block.

Comment: I've just learnt something new from reading what you have just written. Thanks!

Comment: A general rule in large projects is *Don't surprise your coworkers*.  As a student, it's *don't surprise yourself*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is I got the answer correct.

```
for(var i=1;i<=20;i++)
{

if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0)
{
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
else if(i%3 === 0)
{
    console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else if(i%5 === 0)
{
    console.log("Buzz");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

The result will be:

> 1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz
>   19 Buzz

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the ¨=¨

```
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i%3===0 && i%5===0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } 
    else if (i%3===0) {
         console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else if (i%5===0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } 

    else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to add the explanations to your answers

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1 ; i<=20 ; i++){
    if (i%3===0 && i%5!=0){
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i%5===0 && i%3!=0){
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0 ){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");    
    } else {
        console.log (i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=1;
while (i<21)
{    
    if(i%3!==0 && i%5!==0)
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
    if(i%3===0 && i%5===0 )
    {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
    else if(i%3===0)
    {
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else if(i%5===0)
    {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }   

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Javascript, but I know some Python and I've come across the same problem. Maybe this can help. I'm sure someone can just translate this for Javascript.

*Here's the original problem:*
**Loop through the numbers between 1 and 20. If a number is divisible by 3, print Hip. If the number is divisible by 7, print “Hooray”.**

**Here's the code for python for a similar problem:**

```
for numbers in range(1,21):
    if numbers % 3 !=0 and numbers % 7 != 0:
        print(numbers)
    if numbers % 3 == 0:
            print("Hip")
    if numbers % 7 == 0:
            print("Hooray")
```

**Here's the output:**

1
2
Hip
4
5
Hip
Hooray
8
Hip
10
11
Hip
13
Hooray
Hip
16
17
Hip
19
20